Paying a parking fine when I don't trust the recipient
I realized post factum that I forgot to pay for parking at a country park in the UK. There were signs and payment machines, but for various reasons I forgot to do it.
Today I got a payment notice from, it seems, the outsourced manager of the parking, initialparking.co.uk . Their digital footprint is of a genuine parking enforcement company, but using unpleasant practices, such as fining even over tiny overruns, fining people who entered carparks but left without finding a free space, or placing broken payment machines and then fining people. It is the only company I ever saw on Trustpilot with a score of 1.1
Looking at their webpage, payment options are by phone (card), online by card via their own card processor (no 3rd party option like PayPal or stripe), or via cheque. The payment processor (econ6) has 0 online reviews, or any presence at all. The letter includes pictures and timestamps that tally with my visit. It is the only time I have been there, so it would be very hard for someone to spoof these details.
So... I know I forgot to pay, and I am happy to pay a fine. The letter itself appears legit. However, I don't want to part with my debit card details, given the scammy appearance of the company. Payment by cheque would be possible, if awkward, but I cannot get confirmation of payment - again, I don't trust the company to act in good faith.
Any suggestions as to what can be done? Do I have a good chance requesting payment by bank transfer (where they never handle my card details)? I'm contemplating paying, then cancelling the card, but that is of course somewhat inconvenient.
Another idea I just saw is that apparently Klarna (which I don't otherwise use) does do a one time Visa card, with a spending limit. I can't find any reviews of this particular service though. Might that be a good option?

but I cannot get confirmation of payment - cashed cheque? Also, what about paying with a credit card?

@littleadv I don't trust the vendor to keep my card details secure, I'd be concerned about my card details being compromised, by careless handling or otherwise. As for cheque, I don't have their bank details. The cheque option means sending them a paper cheque by post.

Credit cards have very robust anti-fraud protections and warranties. To your point, it's the least sensitive piece of information you can provide anyone from all the options you've listed. Worst case you report a fraudulent transaction and get a new card if something happens, no other damage to you as long as you pay attention to your card account. As to cheques, even paper cheque has to be cashed and posted to your account - that's a proof of payment.

I can send a cheque in good time, the company can be awkward and apply penalty fares for late payment - I cannot easily timestamp the payment, as it were.

You can read reviews of Klarna's virtual credit card by filtering their reviews on TrustPilot with a search for "virtual": https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/klarna.com?search=virtual

Any UK bank will revert and refund a fraudulent payment after a simple phonecall, I would not worry about it.

FWIW, Deutsche Bahn Personenverkehr also currently has a trustpilot rating of 1.1

@Bennet "I cannot easily timestamp the payment" Recorded delivery to the registered address at companies house does that, but does not address the privacy issues.

Actual fraudulent use of your financial instruments are covered by insurance and banks won't really waste time fighting you on it. The real threat is always YOU, where you fully authorize transactions and then claim that they are "fake"... sorry, they were not fake, but you were scammed, and insurance doesn't cover those.

@JackAidley That used to be true. Barclays, which I think is a UK bank but I'm using them in Germany, has made the chargeback process so complicated that I wouldn't bother for small charges. You have to file it in the app, wait several weeks for their answer, then answer them within one week, submit proof of everything else you tried to get your money back, and then wait again while essentially checking the app every other day or you will miss their deadline, in which case they will simply close the case.

@littleadv - good point that the credit card really IS the safest way to pay (but not a DEBIT card, which the OP mentioned). Worth mentioning that for some people, getting a new card can be a very significant investment of time if they have many accounts that use that card for recurring payments.

If this is a parking fine incurred on an international trip, you have another option - just ignore it.  What's the management company going to do, take you to (international) court?  If you're local to the UK though, it appears that ignoring a private parking fine became a bad idea around 2015.

A credit card is the best form of payment in this scenario, except for paying cash in person of course if that were an option. A credit card gives you several benefits:

Immediate confirmation of the payment and amount. Then final confirmation a few days later.
Much easier to deal with fraud if your account numbers do get leaked. Especially compared to giving your bank account details for a draft or using a debit card.
Like you said, you can pay the fine then zero the card and cancel it. But in my opinion, that is a bit of an overreaction.

You may even be able to use a service (from your CC-issuing bank or a third-party) to generate a one time use, temporary card number. This essentially removes any chance of fraud on the parking companies part. Or at least moves it to a more scrupulous company.

are you in the UK? While I agree with the meat of your answer, I have never seen a UK CC provider that offers virtual / one-time-use credit cards as per your last para, other than Klarna as already mentioned by the OP. They seem much more common in the US, from what I've seen here.

This is a fine i.e. there is an obligation to pay: surely this implies that the Legal Tender rules are relevant and they are /obliged/ to accept cash?

Another advantage to using a credit card, assuming you pay at least the minimum amount every month, is building up a good credit score.  (That may become important if you don't yet have a mortgage or other loan, but later want to get one.)  And of course, if you pay it off in full every month, a card with no annual fee costs you nothing.  (It may even earn you a tiny amount, from extra interest in your bank account during the month.)

@MarkMorganLloyd it's not a fine - only a court can impose one of those. It's probably labelled a "Penalty Charge Notice"

@AakashM it's still a debt that might invoke the Legal Tender rules I think. Not a lawyer though!

@Vicky while not a physical bank, Revolut is a credit card (well, debit card) provider based in the UK and does offer one-time-use cards.

@AakashM That is no doubt true, but they are still claiming that you owe them a certain amount in a position in which you cannot revert the transaction (canonical example: a meal you've just eaten vs a takeaway that's about to be handed to you).

Neither of the first two claimed benefits of a credit card are likely to be true in the UK. Most likely you can immediately check online for payments, even if your bank isn't giving you an instant notification on your phone; and it's  easy to challenge and reverse fraudulent payments on a debit card. Credit cards don't make it any easier.

@JackAidley With the caveat that I am not in the UK; I would still think the CC is better for the sole reason of: in the case of fraud, it is the CC-issuing bank's money that is tied up until the transaction is resolved, instead of your own cash from a bank account.

@Nosjack: The bank will usually immediately free the money when the transaction is challenged so it's only true for the time between the transaction being enacted and the person noticing and contacting their bank but I think in practice that won't matter. YMMV :)

Wise also offers disposable virtual cards to UK customers.

Another option could be Revolut, an online bank based in the UK, which also offers single use, throwaway virtual cards for online transactions. You would need to get an account with them first, and then you can create your virtual card.
Even if you don't create a virtual card, you are free to transfer only the funds you need to pay your charge into the Revolut account, meaning that nobody can steal any more than that anyway.
Revolut are a trusted company, they have a 4.1 rating on Trustpilot as of this writing, and I have personally been using them for several years, both privately and at work (the company I work for uses them to issue company cards and pay employees).

Wise is another option for virtual cards.

This is the paranoid answer! A credit/debit card will record that the payment was made (so no late charge can be levied) and the number being throwaway will ensure no further payment will be authorized afterwards.

Write the cheque.
The nice thing about cheques is that if the payment is disputed then there is a record of who cashed it and where the money went. If they claim they didn't get it then just tell them you paid. If they try to make a court claim the record will show they deposited it. Also, because you are in the UK, they cannot make withdrawals from your account just using the info on the cheque. If you want to pay extra for additional peace of mind, send it recorded delivery.
You should not be as concerned as you seem to be be about the reputation of the company. They may not be concerned about their reputation, but the "country park" that contracts with them probably is. If they start stealing people's money, and it becomes public knowledge then their customers will drop them like a hot brick. High pressure and devious tactics is one thing, and probably accounts for the low TrustPilot score. Stealing money is something else again.

The primary problem with a cheque would be if they received it, dropped it in the bin, and then sent a new notice with an additional late penalty—if they don't deposit it, there's no positive proof that you sent it. (And you might have to pay to stop the cheque.) Even if you posted it with tracking and required a signature, you can't prove there was a cheque in the envelope they signed for.
Now of course, there's not much chance they'd do this—I'm sure it's a much better use of their time to take your money. But that's the main risk of posting a cheque to settle a debt.

If I was in that situation  (I also think it's unlikely) I would not bother to stop the cheque, and I would absolutely refuse to send more money.  "I sent you a cheque, if you lost it that's your problem". The company doesn't have the power to enforce the fine by any means other than debt collection. Quite quickly it becomes no longer worth it to them to chase you up, and if you have a record that you wrote the cheque a court is as likely to believe you as them. Even if the lost cheque is eventually found and cashed by a lucky dumpster-diver you are no worse off than if you had paid the fine.

The not so nice thing about cheques is that people can and do copy the details off real ones to produce fake ones.

That would be fraud and a criminal offence, which makes it very unlikely that the parking company would do it. It's also an offence that's fairly easy to track, which makes it only a useful fraud if you can run away as soon as you've done it.

For that sort of thing (and relatively trustworthy recipients) I tend to use Paypal if the recipient accepts it- avoids giving CC or bank account information out for a one-time transaction. But if that's not an option..
You could get a postal order (in the US it would be called a "Postal Money Order").
You can check whether it has been cashed by filling out this online form.
Similarly, in the US you can check the status from this online form.

I have a special card for this kind of payments. In my country it's called "Visa Debet", and can not be over drafted.
When buying something from a website I do not completely trust, I place the amount + approximately 1$ on this account, and pay with the card.
Anyone trying to draw more than that will be rejected.
This was also very useful when I bought an app for my daughters phone with my regulary card, and later was billed for some music subscribtion costing me 15$ a month (she thought it was free and signed up).
I could not get my card erased from her phone because "there were a subscription" even though it was cancelled, but I could change it to my visa debet card!
After some time with warnings that the service would be cancelled (!!) they stopped the service, and that was it.

Do you mean "Visa Debit"? If so then the OP has already explained why they don't want to use their debit card. Or if you do mean something different genuinely called Visa Debet that is only in your country, then how is that useful to the OP in the UK? This is a Q&A site and not a general discussion forum.

@Vicky It's the kind of card where you can not draw more than there is on the card. Most cards can be over drafted, so there i a minus amount you have to cover.
"Visa Debet" can not, so you can never loose more than what is in the account.
I believe there are similar card types in UK, and most of the world for that matter.

In the UK if you have a current account with a debit card, it depends on the account type whether it will be permitted to go into overdraft or not, so the OP could just open a separate current account with no overdraft permitted, use the debit card to pay the fine, and then close the account. However they described that option already as "somewhat inconvenient" so I really don't think this answer adds anything.

@Vicky "Visa Debet" does appear to exist: https://abb-bank.az/en/ferdi/kartlar/tamkart-debet-kartlari/tamgenc-debet

@AaronF right, in Azerbaijan....

@Vicky As I read the question, I understand it as paying with his current card, then canceling it, thus requiring a new card and all card information on various regular payments to be altered. This is certainly inconvenient. My suggestion is to have an other account, permanent, for this purpose: Paying one-time to questionable websites in a way that will prevent them for taking more than you allow.
